# How to specify indent in jq config file?

Tags: jq

Instead of always giving the `--indent n` flag on the command line, I would like to specify this in a config file (or library or module file – I'm not sure what the correct terminology is).

I tried putting various things in `~/.jq`, such as `indent: 4` or `--indent 4`, but they always gave me a compile error when I invoked `jq`.  I looked at the manual but couldn't see any information on how to do this, nor find anything in the issues on GitHub.

Is it possible?

Comment: `~/.jq` and other files are used for libraries/modules (importing more jq code). jq as a program does not have a config file (only colors can be configured using the `JQ_COLORS` environment variable). You could, however, set an `alias` that includes the `--indent` option, e.g. `alias jq='/usr/bin/jq --indent 4'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `~/.jq` file contains jq code such as function definitions. It's not a config file in the classical sense.

Most shells support aliases and you could set one yourself, e.g. in `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`/`~/.bash_aliases` with:

```
alias jq='jq --indent 4'
```

When invoked in an interactive shell, the alias will be resolved to the command including the option. Note however that aliases are ignored in shell scripts (i.e. non-interactive mode) by default.